# Como corregir el contenido corrido a la izquierda, con Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

El contenido me ha quedado corrido al lado izquierdo cuando lo que estoy tratando es que me quede centrado y no identifico por que me sucede eso.

*Anexo una imagen.*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
.nosotros{
    background: no-repeat center center; 
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: 600px;
}

.texto-nosotros {
 margin-top: 200px;
}

.caja-nosotros {
   width: 100%;
    height:inherit;    
    padding: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="nosotros" style="background-image: url(imagenes/parallax.png); background-size: 100%;">
    
        <article>
          <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-2">
                  <div class="texto-nosotros">
                        <h1 class="text-center"><b>ACERCA DE</b> “JOSÉ MIGUEL, ARTE Y BELLEZA”</h1><br>

                    <div class="caja-nosotros">
                        <p>Durante más de 15 años de profesionalismo, experiencia y servicios, José Miguel Sanchez Gonzalez, tenia la 
                        firme idea de crear un espacio para la gente actual, moderna y vanguardista, es asi, como en el 2010 abre sus 
                        puertas “José Miguel arte y belleza” como una gran alternativa a los grandes y prestigiosos centros de estetica 
                        de la ciudad de Bogotá, en la que se ofrecen productos y servicios de gran calidad a precios apropiados.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
         </article>>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La clase `offset-md-2` no existe, cambiala por `col-md-offset-1` y debería comportarse como deseas.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row" style="border:1px solid green;width:50%;margin-left:25%;padding:20px 0px 20px 0px">
  <div style="border:1px solid red" class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
    Div centrado
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Para centrarlo, además, col-md-10 debería ser col-md-8 (2 columnas libres por cada lado)

Comment: Cierto, o el offset a 1, ahora modifico, gracias por el apunte!

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

Podés intentar solucionarlo aplicándole al `div` dentro de `<article>` la clase `class = "justify-content-center"` y/o removiéndole el `offset`.

Comment: Puedes darle al boton "Copiar a respuesta" e implementar tu cambio para que el autor pueda probar el codigo. ^^ Mira [answer] para mejorar tu respuesta. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Solo tienes un error en esta parte:

No le estas diciendo que no tome todo la grilla para centrarse, solo tienes que cambiar eso por esto, `<div class="col-md-12 offset-md-2">`

```css
.nosotros {
  background: no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 600px;
}

.texto-nosotros {
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.caja-nosotros {
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="nosotros" style="background-image: url(http://cdn.homedit.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/137CLUB2ST.png); background-size: 100%;">

    <article>
      <div class="col-md-12 offset-md-2">
        <div class="texto-nosotros">
          <h1 class="text-center"><b>ACERCA DE</b> “JOSÉ MIGUEL, ARTE Y BELLEZA”</h1><br>

          <div class="caja-nosotros">
            <p>Durante más de 15 años de profesionalismo, experiencia y servicios, José Miguel Sanchez Gonzalez, tenia la firme idea de crear un espacio para la gente actual, moderna y vanguardista, es asi, como en el 2010 abre sus puertas “José Miguel arte
              y belleza” como una gran alternativa a los grandes y prestigiosos centros de estetica de la ciudad de Bogotá, en la que se ofrecen productos y servicios de gran calidad a precios apropiados.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cambia la linea `<div class="col-md-10 offset-md-2">` por esta `<div class="col-lg-12">`

Acá puedes ver la documentación http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-options